# jQuery - hide an HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to hide a form, using jQuery, when a function is triggered; however, the form is not hidden and there is no error shown when I inspect the displayed page in Chrome.

I am using the jQuery: `$("#showYMAward").hide();`

HTML:

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showYMAwards">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h3>Joey Award Update</h3>
                    <!-- Place for Group Button -->
                    <div class="input-select" id="img-container1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
function getYMsFunction(val_AwardID) {

    $("#showYMAward").hide();

    alert('Hidden: ');
    sessionStorage.setItem('ssAwardID', val_AwardID);

    $('#ymTable tbody > tr').remove();

    var dataToBeSent  = {
            ssAwardID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAwardID'),
            ssAwardGroupNo : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAwardGroupNo'),
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "GetYMandAwardDates",
        data : dataToBeSent,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
    })
    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured getting the Youth Members');
    })
    .done(function(responseJson1a) {

        $('#showAward-container').html("");

        var dataToBeSent  = {
                ssAwardID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAwardID'),
        };

        //Get the Award Image
        $.ajax({
            data : dataToBeSent,
            type: "POST",
            url: "AwardImageView",
            cache: false
        })
        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No Award found')){
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('No Award found.');
                }else{
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured getting the Award Image');
                }
        })
        .done(function(responseJson1) {
            dataType: "json";
            // JSON response to populate the Award images and dates
            $(responseJson1).appendTo($("#showAward-container"));
        });


        dataType: "json";

        // JSON response to populate the Award images and names
        $(responseJson1a).appendTo($("#ymDetails"));
    });
}
```

I have placed an alert after the hide just in case it is hiding then showing again. This is not the case.

Comment: There is typo error `$("#showYMAward").hide();` need to be `$("#showYMAwards").hide();`

Comment: Voted to Close: *a simple typographical error.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning of your JS you have a typo at `$("#showYMAward").hide();`, it should be `$("#showYMAwards").hide();` based on how you wrote it in your HTML. Change that and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is typo error in your code `$("#showYMAward").hide();` need to be `$("#showYMAwards").hide();`. Since there is no element with id `showYMAward` in your code, it will not hide any element.

```js
$('#hideShowYMAward').on('click', function() {
  $("#showYMAward").hide();
});
$('#hideShowYMAwards').on('click', function() {
  $("#showYMAwards").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showYMAwards">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Joey Award Update</h3>
        <!-- Place for Group Button -->
        <div class="input-select" id="img-container1">
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>

<button id="hideShowYMAwards">Click me this will work</button>
<button id="hideShowYMAward">Click me this will not work</button>
```